# Several span's sharing same border and box-shadow

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, svg

I'm trying to code something like this [image] but can't seems to figure out how to make same border and shadow for different lines of text.

```
<span>Some title will be here</span>
```

This is a dynamic content title, so it may be two lines or three lines of text. I'm looking for any solution, including using canvas or svg, but text should remain editable.

Thanks!

Comment: Example you shown is Image, I Never did such shaped Div. 
But this border and Shadow can be given to a full text or a square Div element,

Comment: Yep, thing is that I need exactly such shaped Div or Span with different width of lines, that have border on surrounding sides and shadow from all that block. 

I have absolutely no problem creating that shadow and border from square div block, but that's not my case :)

Comment: What are the rules you use to split the text into multiple lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to use a static span to create such effect without specifying an unique id or class. So here is a possible solution and hope that helps:

```css
span {
    display: block;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    transform: translate(4px, -4px);
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}

.first {
    border-bottom: none;
}

.second {
    z-index: 2;
}

.last {
    border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

div {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #000000;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div><span class="first">SOME</span></div>
<div><span class="second">TITLE WILL</span></div>
<div><span class="last">BE HERE</span></div>
```

EDITED:

The approach here is just a trick and fairly simple by applying a higher z-index to the shorter element and move it up or down using margin to cover the longer element. This would only work if you know the width of each span beforehand. However, if the span is generated dynamically, you will have to use other mean such as php or javascript to get the width and apply css accordingly.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to achieve! Thank you very much!

Comment: Whoops, That's not working when first line and the line is longer than the second one :( Here is an example http://i.stack.imgur.com/iZwy0.jpg

Comment: You can use the same concept to achieve that IF you know the width of each span before hand. However, if the widths are unknown, than you will have to detective the width and apply css accordingly. You can do that by either php or javascript.